# Javascript still runs even though I have removed it from my application - Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So Im working with an application in Blazor WebAssembly. I had a script in the index.html file, but when I removed the script and ran the program the script was still running. It's like I havent removed it or managed to save my changes. Does anyone know how to fix this or can tell my why this happens?

Comment: Clear your browsers cache

Comment: @BrianParker Probably should have thought of that. Thanks!